# What's a good way to achieve fast movement of an image following the cursor?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I've been working on a chess GUI for a short while. Am new to PyQt5. Already coded quite a bit though, so for the sake of generality (and to keep the lines of code here to a minimum), I'll just treat it as any board game that has a grid, and has pieces navigating the grid. I managed to get drag and drop behaviour in different ways, but they all had some (for me significant) downside. In any case, the particular interaction I am trying to implement is 'grabbing' a piece from a certain square (on click) and then having it follow the mouse, until it is dropped onto a different square (on release).

### Version info

PyQt5 version: 5.15.0
Windows version: Windows 10 Pro 64 bits (10.0)

### First Approach

Initially I was hoping simply moving a `QLabel` with a given pixmap might do the trick but when moving the mouse quite fast, it seems the drawing is not fast enough to keep up with the movement of the mouse. As a result, it looks like the image phases in and out of existence, or only half of it renders before it gets redrawn. Tried something similar using `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`, and some `QGraphicsItem` objects and making them movable. But the results were the same, image cutting off while trying to keep up with the cursor. Example code attempting to use QGraphicsView:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, 
                             QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.pm = QPixmap(70,70)
        self.pm.fill(Qt.black)

        self.item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.pm)

        self.setGeometry(100,100,900,900)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.viewWidth = 800
        self.viewHeight = self.viewWidth
        self.view.setGeometry(0,0,self.viewWidth, self.viewHeight)

        self.bk = self.scene.addPixmap(self.pm)

        self.bk.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With this code, if you grab the 'piece' and go back and forth with the mouse at a high speed, I mainly see half/a quarter of the image. In the middle of the area I move the object, I usually don't see the object at all. Video of this in action: https://vimeo.com/user41790219

### Second Approach

I found the `QDrag` class, and with it, a reasonable way of creating draggable pieces. It looks fantastic, absolutely no problems once the drag actually started, the image moves very smoothly. However, I wanted the drag to start on a `mousePressEvent`, and have it start immediately. With 'start immediately', I rather mean render the pixmap at the mouse location on click. This does not occur on Windows. Now, as stated in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#exec, the `QDrag.exec_()` is blocking on Windows. It says that once entering exec, it will call `processEvents()` frequently to make sure the GUI stays responsive. This is all fine, but on Windows it does not render the image assigned to QDrag, until the mouse has moved some amount. This is a shame, because on Linux it actually looks kinda snappy (on click it moves to the mouse instantly). Maybe it's a bit petty, but I really want to have the piece instantly snap to the mouse. This is some sample code I kinda pieced together/came up using QDrag and QPushbuttons that shows this behaviour:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtSvg import *
import sys

BOARDSIZE = 500
SQUARESIZE = 100
PIECESIZE = 70
FILES = 5
RANKS = 5

class Square(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap=None, size=100, dark=False):
        super(Square,self).__init__()
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.size = size
        if dark:
            self.bg = '#8CA2AD'
        else:
            self.bg = '#DEE3E6'

        self.setFixedWidth(size)
        self.setFixedHeight(size)
        if self.pixmap is not None:
            self.setIcon(QIcon(self.pixmap))
            self.setIconSize(self.pixmap.rect().size())
        self.setStyle()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def setStyle(self):
        self.setStyleSheet(f"""
            QPushButton {{
                background-color:{self.bg};
                color:#ffffff;
                border-width:0px;
                border-radius: 0px;
                padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }}
            """)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.pixmap is not None:
                s = self.pixmap.width()
                drag = QDrag(self)
                drag.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
                mime = QMimeData()
                mime.setText('piece')
                drag.setMimeData(mime)
                drag.setHotSpot(QPoint(int(s/2) , int(s/2)))
                self.setIcon(QIcon())
                self.pixmap = None
                drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction | Qt.CopyAction)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        pixmap = QPixmap(PIECESIZE, PIECESIZE)
        pixmap.fill(Qt.black)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.setIcon(QIcon(pixmap))
        self.setIconSize(pixmap.rect().size())

class Board(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=BOARDSIZE, height=BOARDSIZE):
        super(Board,self).__init__(parent)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setFixedWidth(self.width)
        self.setFixedHeight(self.height)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(0)
        self.setAcceptDrops(False)

        size = int(self.width/FILES)
        pixmap = QPixmap(PIECESIZE, PIECESIZE)
        pixmap.fill(Qt.black)

        dark = True
        for row in range(0,FILES):
            for col in range(0,RANKS):
                if row == 0 or row == 4:
                    pm = pixmap
                else:
                    pm = None
                square = Square(pixmap=pm,size=size,dark=dark)
                grid.addWidget(square, row, col)
                dark = not dark
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setAcceptDrops(False)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()

        self.board = Board(parent=self)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,BOARDSIZE+50,BOARDSIZE+50)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.board)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But in this example, when you click, the drag only visually initiates after the mouse has been moved, I would want it to visually initiate immediately after the mouse is clicked. This is Windows-specific.

### Mention-worthy stuff

I found that on a `QApplication`, you can set the startDragTime and startDragDistance, but after setting those to some values (including 0 and -1), nothing happened, so I assumed they are just symbolic variables to be used as globals.

### Question

What I'm looking for is the QDrag behaviour after the mouse moves slightly, i.e. the smooth movement during the drag + that it shows up immediately after the `mousePressEvent`. I'm also fine with any anything involving the use of QObjects with a pixmap and simply moving them, as long as the movement under the cursor looks smooth (doesnt clip or cut off). Any hints/ideas, or resources I may have missed are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem with the given example? You didn't complete the phrase. Also, while you can achieve this using standard drag and drop, for your case using QGraphicsView might be the better choice anyway. If you got graphics issues using graphics items, you should show us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of that, because "images cutting off" should not happen when moving items, so it might be a bug or, more probably, an error in your implementation.

Comment: Apologies, I finished the sentence, completely slipped past me while writing, hopefully that clarifies what I found to a 'problem'. I added another code example using the QGraphicsView. Agreed, it's very likely I did not implement it correctly, but had trouble finding relevant resources for PyQt5.. Either way, thanks for the response

Comment: With the QGraphicsView example I cannot reproduce your issue, the black square is always painted correctly no matter how fast I move it. I'm on Linux, though, it *might* be an issue related to Qt and windows (and/or graphics driver). Can you provide a screenshot (maybe taken from a screen capture in video) of the problem? Also, what version of PyQt do you use and what version of Windows?

Comment: Added it to the main question, wasnt sure where the appropriate location was for these data..